# C++ abort() on abstract class object pointer call inside a function

Tags: c++

I've got an abstract class pendulum with pure virtual function period() and two descendants(math and spring) implementing function period().

I've got a pendulum **pendArray = new pendulum*[n].
I fill the array with math and spring class object pointers and pass the array to the findMaxPeriod(pendulum **a) function:

```
void findMaxPeriod(pendulum **a) 
{
    pendulum *maxPend = new math();
    double maxPeriod = 0;
    double period1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        pendulum *pend = a[i];
        period1 = pend->period();
        if (period1 > maxPeriod)
        {
            maxPend = a[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "max period pendulum is " << maxPend << ". It's period is " << maxPend->period();
}
```

It crashes on the

```
period1 = pend->period();
```

with "debug error! abort() has been called"

What am I doing wrong?
Here is all my code: https://hello-site.ru/share/Abort-called-problem/
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not post offsite links with your code, include all relevant code within the question itself.

Comment: Also, your issue has nothing to do with the code you posted.  It has everything to do with storing pointers to local variables and those variables going out of scope.  Since you didn't post your code here, that is as far as I am going to go with letting you know what the issue is.  Post the code here, and you will get a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thank you. I'll post it the right way next time.

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
math pendM;
cin >> pendM;
pendArray[i] = &pendM;
```

In the third line, you've place a pointer-to-`pendM` into your array, but `pendM` gets destroyed immediately after that line, when it goes out of scope.  If you want to keep it around (and thus avoid a dangling pointer in your `pendArray`) you'll need to allocate it from the heap instead of on the stack.

Same thing goes for `pendS` in the next block below that.

Comment: Wow, didn't see a difference between heap and stack constructors before. You've opened my eyes, thanks!

Comment: Note the constructor-method called is the same in both cases, it's just the object-creation syntax (`math pendM;` vs `math * pendM  = new math();`) that makes the difference.